# Hibernate: getter of @OneToMany field in entity returns null in junit test

Tags: java, hibernate, junit

I have three entities (there're also getters and setters for every field):

```
public class IndicatorSet { 

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NaturalId
    @Column(unique=true, nullable=false)
    private String code;

    @Column(nullable=false)
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinTable(
            name = "indicator_set_indicators",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "indicator_set_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "indicator_id")
            )
    private List<Indicator> indicators;
}

public class Indicator {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable=false, unique=true)
    private String code;
}

public class IndicatorSetIndicator {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="indicator_id", nullable=false)
    private Indicator indicator;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="indicator_set_id", nullable=false)
    private IndicatorSet indicatorSet;
}
```

I put in database an IndicatorSet, Indicators and connect it with IndicatorSetIndicator table on my server and in junit test before running the following code.

```
IndicatorSet set = indicatorSetDAO.get(idOfSet);
List<Indicator> indicators = set.getIndicators();
```

When I invoke this code on server it works and I see my Indicators in list.
When I try to invoke this code in junit test, I see in list null reference.
And that's strange.

Also when I invoke the following code in junit test, it works perfect and indicators appears in list:

```
IndicatorSet set = indicatorSetDAO.get(idOfSet);
List<Indicator> indicators = indicatorSetIndicatorDAO.getIndicatorsBySet(set);
```

DAO uses Criteria API to get list of indicators.
There're this set of annotations on class with tests:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:TestContext.xml")
@Transactional
@TestExecutionListeners({ DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class, DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class,
    TransactionalTestExecutionListener.class, SessionRequestTestExecutionListener.class })
```

TestContext.xml:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
    <beans [schemes]>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <context:component-scan base-package="org.example.monitoring" />

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <jdbc:embedded-database id="dataSource" type="HSQL" />

    <bean id="liquibase" class="liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="changeLog" value="classpath:db-changelog.xml" />
        <property name="contexts" value="test" />
        <!-- <property name="dropFirst" value="true" /> -->
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name='packagesToScan' value='pro.sisit.etalon.monitoring.entities' />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.autocommit">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.CustomScopeConfigurer">
        <property name="scopes">
            <map>
                <entry key="request">
                    <bean class="org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestScope" />
                </entry>
                <entry key="session">
                    <bean class="org.springframework.web.context.request.SessionScope" />
                </entry>
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Configuration of Hibernate not in test enviroment:

```
    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/monitoring" />
    </bean>

    <bean id='sessionFactory'
        class='org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean'>
        <property name='dataSource' ref='dataSource' />
        <property name='packagesToScan' value='pro.sisit.etalon.monitoring.entities'/>
        <property name='hibernateProperties'>
            <props>
                <prop key='hibernate.dialect'>org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory</prop>
                <prop key='hibernate.show_sql'>false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.charSet">UTF-8</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">UTF-8</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

How can I make my code work in JUint test?

Comment: Please add the `TestContext.xml`, and the hibernate test configuration if it not in the `TestContext.xml`

Comment: Update: I've added TestContext.xml with hibernate configuration and Hibernate configuration for application when it's runned on server.

Comment: What is missing is the code of your test. My guess is that you're creating the indicatorSet in the same transaction, and that although you created an indicator with a parent indicatorSet, you neglected to add the indicator to the indicatorSet list, making the objectgraph inconsistent.

Comment: So, I need to add indicator into indicatorSet list also? Or I just need to add and get indicators in two different transactions? What is the right way to test something, that work with database adding data in and getting it out?